# Add one "day" to date but let me choose what time

Tags: php

I need a function to add one day to a date, but a I need to be able to specify the time. Basically I just want to add tomorrows actual, not a day as in 24 hours.

So I have this right now:

```
// add one day but specific time
$endTime = strtotime('+1 day', time());
```

This does what its supposed to and adds 1 day to the date, but how can I chose the hour, minutes and seconds?

so if I run i right now I get July 17th 10:57 AM, how can I specify the hour? So it will be saved as: July 17th 9:00 AM, in unix timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as you'd expect if you supply the time.

```
$endTime = strtotime('+1 day 9:00 AM');
```

But if what you really want is to just get tomorrows date regardless of the time, you really don't want `+1 day`. Instead try this use `tomorrow`...

```
// will give you tomorrows date instead of +24 hours
$endTime = strtotime('tomorrow 9:00 AM');
```

Checkout the [relative date formats](http://php.net/datetime.formats.relative) accepted by date time functions in the manual for more details.