# Add given time to tomorrows date in PHP

Tags: php

This might be fairly easy but can't seem to figure it out.

This is what I want to get;

```
$t = 12:00
$todaysdate = 2015-11-30
```

I want to get `$tomorrowsdate` with `$t` appended to it

```
$tomorrowsdate = 2015-12-01 12:00
```

So basically I want to be able to add a given time to next day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add one "day" to date but let me choose what time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449755/add-one-day-to-date-but-let-me-choose-what-time)

Comment: How can I do something like this `$ntime = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime('+1 day $t));` where `$t` is the time I want to set

Answer (score 1):

It's important to define them as a string if you wanna use `strtotime`. Otherwise, you will get freaky results e.g. the year 1970 ;)

```
$t = '12:00';
$todaysdate = '2015-11-30';

$tomorrowsdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("{$todaysdate} + 1 day")) . " {$t}";
echo $tomorrowsdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase you want to use object oriented style use the following;

```
$today = new DateTime(); //today (2015-12-29)
$tommorow = $today->add(new DateInterval('P1D')); // add one day
echo $tommorow->format('Y-m-d H:i'); // echo results in desired format eg. 2015-12-30 12:36
// incase that 12:00 is important..
$tommorow->setTime(12,0);
echo $tommorow->format('Y-m-d H:i'); // 2015-12-30 12:00
```